# Convert any datatime format to single format in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `date_time` column in my dataframe(`df`) as below :

```
date-time
2020/9/23
22-09-2020
20200924
2020-10-10 11:24:00
```

I want to convert all these date in single format. I am trying below code to handle but getting `None` value for last `date-time`:

```
def format_date(string):
    for fmt in ["%Y/%m/%d", "%d-%m-%Y", "%Y%m%d","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"]:
        try:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(string, fmt).date()
        except ValueError:
            continue


for dates in df['date-time']:
    print(format_date(dates))

2020-09-23
2020-09-22
2020-09-24
None
```

Comment: Why are you raising the error deliberately?

Comment: @sai- If I remove the error ,I will get `'None'` for last `date-time`

Comment: You have typos in `"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` and `202009024`.

Comment: use `%Y` for a 4 digit year, as you did before. `%y` is for 2 digits.

Comment: @Wups-Thanks this is only creating issue. I changed `%y` to `%Y` and it works.

Comment: @Adityasharma it is returning None because you are not able to find a match

Comment: Check out [`dateutil`](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil). It automatically converts date strings (indifferent of format) to `datetime` objects.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I tested your code by replacing  df['date-time'] with df_list below.

```
df_list = ['2020/9/23','22-09-2020','20200924','2020-10-10 11:24:00']
```

And it prints all corect dates.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the below code in regard to your question and it is working for me.

```
from datetime import datetime

def format_date(text):
    for fmt in ('%Y/%m/%d', '%d-%m-%Y', '%Y%m%d','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(text, fmt)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError('no valid date format found for:'+text)

print(format_date('2020/9/23'))
print(format_date('22-09-2020'))
print(format_date('20200924'))
print(format_date('2020-10-10 11:24:00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you have to write a function to do this work. Can't you use the builtin function provided by pandas to do this please?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date-time':['2020/9/23','22-09-2020',
                                '20200924','2020-10-10 11:24:00']})
print (df)
df['date-time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date-time'])
print (df)
```

Original DataFrame:

```
             date-time
0            2020/9/23
1           22-09-2020
2             20200924
3  2020-10-10 11:24:00
```

Updated DataFrame to datetime format.

```
            date-time
0 2020-09-23 00:00:00
1 2020-09-22 00:00:00
2 2020-09-24 00:00:00
3 2020-10-10 11:24:00
```